# How do fixed Vs rotary wing licences work in Britain?

Tags: helicopter, pilot-certification, fixed-wing, cpl

I am eager to be able to fly both helicopters and fixed wing planes commercially. Would this require two separate Commercial Pilots Licenses or is there some amount of overlap? For example, can you do a fixed wing CPL then upgrade it to a fixed + rotary CPL? How does it work?

I live in England, so are there differences across international borders or is this pretty standardised?

Answer (score 3):

Rotary and fixed wing are different licenses in the UK, whether you are private, commercial or ATPL. You first get a PPL, then a CPL for the type of aircraft, and you must pass the test for each separately. The hours requirements are reduce for each if you have the other aircraft type license, for instance for the CPL-H you can count 50 hours of PIC time if you have a CPL-A, for example, and there are reduced cross-country navigation requirements for the PPL as you've already shown you can navigate from getting the other license. So some training and experience carries over.

EASA countries work on a similar model, the exact requirements vary from member state to member state.

Comment: Thanks! I have lots of work to do then!